# swift firebase fetch followers uid's then fetch their details

Tags: swift, xcode

I would like to fetch a user's followers (in this case they have one follower) then I need to fetch that follower's details to load in a cell to present in a collectionviewcontroller.

I start like this:

```
fileprivate func fetchFollwersUID() {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    Database.database().reference().child("Follwers").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

The snapshot is IfzJrhbtkjesmjHfFXgGcnjvUXO2: IfzJrhbtkjesmjHfFXgGcnjvUXO2

with the key and value both being of the follwer's uid for the key and value (just for this example)

I want to the save key as key then go to firebase.child("Users") and get just that one user's details and append the to an array of users: [User]

```
Database.database().reference().child("Users")    (search for user with "Key")

guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

let user = User(dictionary: dictionary)
self.users.append(user)
self.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

In the end I'm left appending that one user details which later I will do a didSet in my UICollectionViewCell and put their details in my Contacts UICollectionViewController

Answer (score 0):

If you store your user information like this:

```
"Users": {
    "UID1": {
        "Name": "Steve",
        "Email": "ScubaSteve@gmail.com"
    }
    "UID2": {
        ...
    }
}
```

All you need to do is perform a "nested" query

```
fileprivate func fetchFollwersUID() { 
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    Database.database().reference().child("Follwers").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in {
        for child in snap.children {
            let child = child as? DataSnapshot
            if let key = child?.key {
                // query for that users information
                Database.database().reference.child("Users").child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in 
                    guard let dictionary = snap.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                    if let name = dictionary["Name"] as? String, let email = dictionary["Email"] as? String {
                        // do something with that user information
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: thanks for the help though  im not 100% ;  for child in snap.children {
            let child = child as? DataSnapshot
            if let key = child?.key {  are working with my version of xcode firebase and swift

Comment: If that's not working change how you store the data inside followers. You can do "UID": key instead of the actual uid:uid. Then you can cast to a dictionary and get the value at "UID".